# "Network error" while calling a REST api from Outlook app, but 200 Ok from outllook web (Outlook.com)

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I was building an outlook add-in for which i need to call a rest api. While sideloading the add-in in the outlook application in my Mac it is throwing the error below. But, in the outlook.com it is working perfectly fine (200 Ok response). I might be missing something, don't know what. I couldn't fix it. Please help me fixing this problem.

Thanks!!

```
{
  "message": "Network Error",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "createError@https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:613:24\nhandleError@https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:104:25\nwrapFn@https://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:1231:48\nonInvokeTask@https://localhost:3000/vendor.js:34970:43\nrunTask@https://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:180:61\ninvokeTask@https://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:493:45\ninvokeTask@https://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:1634:24\nglobalZoneAwareCallback@https://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:1660:31",
  "config": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8102/api/get-token",
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the version of your Outlook Mac? Are you using Modern Outlook Mac (New Outlook: On)? Is it possible for your to share your addin and manifest with us?

Comment: Also, can you please tell us which REST API you are calling from your add-in?

Comment: 1) Please provide request/response used for REST API? 2) Also which service's REST API you are trying to use - Outlook REST APIs or any other local service? 3) Can you also share "response" you receive in case of success case in Outlook Web?